# Sound isn't playing in Game Maker Studio when interacting with an object

Tags: android, game-maker

I'm making a small game in Game Maker Studio.
I have a piece of code that moves the player to the next room when he touches `obj_star`: this works.
I have another line that tries to play sound_collect when the star is touched, but the game just moves to the next room without playing the sound.
This code is in the Step event

My code is as follows:

```
//Get the player's input
key_right = keyboard_check(vk_right);
key_left = -keyboard_check(vk_left);
key_jump = keyboard_check_pressed(vk_space);

//React to inputs
move = key_left + key_right;
hsp = move * movespeed;
if (vsp < 10) vsp += grav;

if (place_meeting(x,y+1,obj_wall))
{
vsp = key_jump * -jumpspeed
}
//Horizontal Collision
if (place_meeting(x+hsp,y,obj_wall))
{
while(!place_meeting(x+sign(hsp),y,obj_wall))
{
    x += sign(hsp);
}
hsp = 0;
}
x += hsp;

//Vertical Collision
if (place_meeting(x,y+vsp,obj_wall))
{
while(!place_meeting(x,y+sign(vsp),obj_wall))
{
    y += sign(vsp);
}
vsp = 0;
}
y += vsp;

//Sounds
if (place_meeting(x+hsp,y,obj_star))
{
sound_play(sound_collect)
};
//Next Level
if (place_meeting(x+hsp,y,obj_star))
{
room_goto_next()
};
```

Comment: Could you please show us the code where it is changing room? I can't seem to find it in the one you posted. And please specify what the current script is: is this a *step*, *draw*, *key_press*, etc.?

Comment: Sorry about that, edited it in. Also added the fact that it is in a step event.

Comment: Have you tried putting a *show_message* just before *sound_play*, just to see if it really enters the *if* block and at least calls the *sound_play* function?

Comment: I dont know how to do that.

Comment: Just put *show_message("Test")* on a new line just after *sound_play*, but still within the brackets. This will play the sound and show a message that you have to dismiss before the game will change room. It will let the sound the time to play if by any way it was stopped by the *room_goto_next*. If the sounds still doesn't play, then you have a problem with the sound file or index itself.

Comment: I did that, and the sound didnt play. The sound isnt the problem AFAIk because it still plays within the sound folder in game maker.

Comment: Have you tried just playing the sound on a key press? Playing the sound from the GameMaker folder is one thing, but actually playing it in-game is another.

Comment: Ive fixed the problem by chnging the function to audio_sound_play(sound_collect,1,0).

Answer (score 1):

I see multiple problems with your code that I can see. First is the inconsistent use of the semicolon as a terminator:

```
if (place_meeting(x+hsp,y,obj_star))
{
  room_goto_next()
};
```

should be:

```
if (place_meeting(x+hsp,y,obj_star))
{
  room_goto_next();
}
```

Also, because the same condition is being checked, you can combine the two if blocks to clean up the code.

```
if (place_meeting(x+hsp,y,obj_star))
{
  sound_play(sound_collect);
  room_goto_next();
}
```

Don't know if this will solve your problem but it will clean up your code. If it doesn't work try using the `audio_sound_play` function.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the sounds as part of the collision event. When it collides with obj_star You could then say:

```
sound_play(sound_collect);

room_goto_next();
```